# Passing variable between multiple contexts with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I'm writing some tests using `FactoryGirl` and `Rspec`.

**spec/factories/students.rb**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
  end

  factory :student_with_profile_and_identity, class: 'Student' do
    after(:create) do |student|
      create(:profile, profileable: student)
      create(:student_identity, student: student)
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/profiles.rb**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    birthday { Faker::Date.birthday(15, 150) }
    sequence(:email) { |i| "profile_#{i}@email.com" }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(6, 72, true, true) }
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/student_identities.rb**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student_identity do
    provider { ['facebook.com', 'google.com', 'twitter.com'].sample }
    uid { Faker::Number.number(10) }
  end
end
```

**spec/requests/authorizations_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Authorizations', type: :request do
  describe 'POST /v1/authorizations/sign_in' do
    let!(:student) { create(:student_with_profile_and_identity) }

    context 'when the request is valid' do
      subject do
        post '/v1/authorizations/sign_in',
             params: credentials
      end

      context "user signs up via social network" do
        let(:credentials) do
          {
            authorization: {
              student: {
                profile_attributes: {
                  email: student.profile.email
                },
                student_identities_attributes: {
                  provider: student.student_identities[0].provider,
                  uid: student.student_identities[0].uid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        end

        it 'returns an authentication token' do
          subject
          p "1 student.profile.inspect #{student.profile.inspect}"
          expect(json['token']).to(be_present)
        end
      end

      context 'when the user has already an account' do
        let(:credentials) do
          {
            authorization: {
              email: student.profile.email,
              password: student.profile.password
            }
          }
        end

        it 'returns an authentication token' do
          p "2 student.profile.inspect #{student.profile.inspect}"
          subject
          expect(json['token']).to(be_present)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Almost all tests are passing... the problem is that:

It's creating a new *student* in every context. I'd expect the `let!(:student) { ... }` to be something like *"singleton"*, in other words, once it's created/defined here `let!(:student) { create(:student_with_profile_and_identity) }` it won't be called anymore.

Ex: the logs are like this:

```
"1 student.profile.inspect #<Profile id: 1, email: \"profile_1@email.com\", profileable_type: \"Student\", profileable_id: 1>"

"2 student.profile.inspect #<Profile id: 2, email: \"profile_2@email.com\", profileable_type: \"Student\", profileable_id: 2>"
```

While I'd expect the instances to be the same.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec, [`let` and `let!`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) are the same thing, except that `let` is lazy and `let!` is eager:

> Use `let` to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.
>
> Note that `let` is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time the method it defines is invoked. You can use `let!` to force the method's invocation before each example.

If you want something to persist through all examples, you can use a [before hook](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)...[`before(:context)`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-%60before(:context)%60-block-in-example-group) sounds like it might be what you're wanting. You might be able to setup a helper method that memoizes in a `before` block, to avoid having to use an instance variable everywhere (per [this comment](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/500#issuecomment-2696719)):

```
def student
  @student ||= create(:student_with_profile_and_identity)
end

before(:context) do
  student # force student creation
end
```